# How can I get max number of concurrent streams supported by servere? (Http2.0 - library nghttp2; language: C)

Tags: c, windows, http2, nghttp2

I just started learning about HTTP2.0 protocol and the nghttp2 library. I started with the examples from the project (libevent-client.c (https://nghttp2.org/documentation/tutorial-client.html) and libevent-server.c(https://nghttp2.org/documentation/tutorial-server.html)).
I am trying to find a function in nghttp2 library that gives me the number of concurrent streams supported by the server in the client.

```
static int send_server_connection_header(http2_session_data *session_data) {
  nghttp2_settings_entry iv[1] = {
      {NGHTTP2_SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS, 100}};
  int rv;

  rv = nghttp2_submit_settings(session_data->session, NGHTTP2_FLAG_NONE, iv,
                               ARRLEN(iv));
  if (rv != 0) {
    warnx("Fatal error: %s", nghttp2_strerror(rv));
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
static int session_send(http2_session_data *session_data) {
  int rv;
  rv = nghttp2_session_send(session_data->session);
  if (rv != 0) {
    warnx("Fatal error: %s", nghttp2_strerror(rv));
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In the eventcb callback server send settings, but where is this message
received in the client?

```
if (send_server_connection_header(session_data) != 0 ||
        session_send(session_data) != 0) {
      delete_http2_session_data(session_data);
      return;
}
```

How can I see this setting in the client?

Comment: Without knowing anything about HTTP2, why not open as many streams as you need, and gracefully handle errors telling you that the server can't handle more streams?

Comment: I did this and got error 7 on all the extra streams. Error 7 means REFUSED_STREAM. My question is if I can see in advance how many streams the server supports, so I don't get this error.

Comment: That sounds like the error you need to handle. When you get that, don't create more streams until one of your existing streams finishes.

Comment: And I doubt the number of streams can be pre-fetched, since it could depend on many factors (server configuration, dynamic load-balancing, other connected clients, etc.).

Comment: Well, then why call nghttp2_submit_settings + nghttp2_session_send? Where these settings are sent?